# Why when resizing window there is no space on the left of the input fields?

Tags: css

I have a really quick question. I have developed this css and html with the help of a YouTube tutorial as well as the community. However, I do have a problem and I have spent a good hour trying to solve it but have had no luck. When I resize the window, the vertical line in the center of the page (div="splitter") disappears and there is no space on the left-hand side the input fields either. Can someone please explain why?

Also, if you guys would not mind how does my css code look? Is it correct?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* :focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #ced4da;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.login-form {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.login-form input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

form {
  align-self: center;
}

.splitter {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 0.5px;
  height: 180px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.side-text {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.side-text h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.side-text p {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
      <div class="email-input-field">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailPost">
      </div>
      <div class="password-input-field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwordPost">
      </div>
      <div class="submit-button">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="splitter"></div>
  <div class="side-text">
    <h2>Cold Ops</h2>
    <p>ADMINISTRATION PANEL</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the issue is the 0.5px ... it's a very low value and sometimes get rounded to 0 ... simply use 1px and you are safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `0.5px` width on your splitter. I tried brining it up to `1px`, but saw that it did not help. What did seem to work was setting `min-width` to `1px` as well.

Your css looks OK, but I would suggest looking more into how flex-box works, here is a good article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The reason why there is no space on the left side is because you have not set any. Did you perhaps mean to set the `margin-left` to something instead of `padding-left`?

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem! :) May I ask why using min-width worked and not width? And sorry to bother you, but when you say my CSS looks ok what can I improve? Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped :) I think it worked because, as Temani Afif mentioned in his comment, that width sometimes gets rounded down. Therefore a value set with `min-width` guarantees that it will be at least the number you set. Concerning your css, I meant to say that it looks good, it was just not clear to me if you had a full understanding of flex-box and thought I might show you the guide that I have found very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it happens due to flexbox. I made it work via border. Now it works as expected since border isn't affected by possible dynamic width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* :focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #ced4da;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.login-form {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.login-form input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

form {
  align-self: center;
}

.splitter {
  background-color: grey;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 180px;
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.side-text {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.side-text h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.side-text p {
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
      <div class="email-input-field">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailPost">
      </div>
      <div class="password-input-field">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwordPost">
      </div>
      <div class="submit-button">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="splitter"></div>
  <div class="side-text">
    <h2>Cold Ops</h2>
    <p>ADMINISTRATION PANEL</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally I would do this splitter using border of one of the blocks. Thus you would have less elements.

Comment: Thanks! The splitter is definitely a great idea!